# Elasticsearch keyword and lowercase and aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have previously stored some fields with the mapping "keyword". But, they are case senstive.

To solve this, it is possible to use an analyzer, such as

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_lowercase": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "field": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase"
    }
  }
}
```

But then the Aggregate on term does not work.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [a] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.

It works on mapping type=keyword, but type=keyword does not allow analyzer it seems.

**How do I index it as a lowercase keyword but still make it possible to use aggregation without setting fielddata=true?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using ES 5.2 or above, you can now leverage [`normalizer`s](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) for `keyword` fields. Simply declare your index settings and mappings like this and you're good to go

```
PUT index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "keyword_lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "keyword_lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hope they keep it, since it's experimental

Comment: "experimental" is another way of saying "don't blame us if it's not bug-free", but don't worry, that will stay around.

Comment: Thanks for this! But how can highlight feature work?

Comment: @Daviddd feel free to ask a new question referencing this one and which describes your problem.