# How can we do a key insensitive cardinality aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

We can use cardinality to get a distinct count on a field, however the cardinality is case sensitive... meaning that if we have emails like `user@x.com`, `User@x.com` and `USER@x.com` these will count as 3 emails, however I need this to count as a single email count.

This is the aggregation I am using:

```
  "aggs" : {
        "emails" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "emails.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
```

I would need something like:

```
  "aggs" : {
        "emails" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "emails.keyword",
                "casesensitive": false ????
            }
        }
    }
```

How can we do to make a cardinality aggregation to be key insensitive?

Comment: This asnwer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43492634/4604579 (hint: use a lowercase normalizer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would go with Val's suggestion, here is the query I thought may be useful if you do not have the control of the mapping where I made use of a custom script in [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{ 
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{ 
      "email_count":{ 
         "cardinality":{ 
            "script":{ 
               "source":"doc['email.keyword'].toString().toLowerCase()"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that you would find more details on [`Scripting`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) in the aforementioned link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That would work, too, although just be aware that depending on the amount of data you have, the performance of your cluster might suffer

Comment: Of course @Val, especially if people (at times I, myself) end up writing lot more complicated logic in scripts, and did notice drop in performance in nodes. I just wrote a sample infinite loop and saw this `"reason": "The maximum number of statements that can be executed in a loop has been reached."` That's actually nice!!

Comment: hey @Federico Piazza, was the above answer useful? If not please do let us know more on what you are looking for, we'd be happy to help :)